# C# syntax questions

Tags: c#, syntax, enums, nullable

i have seen the following code in an c# example:

```
public void AddScreen(GameScreen screen, PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer)
{
    screen.ControllingPlayer = controllingPlayer;
    screen.ScreenManager = this;
    screen.IsExiting = false;
}
```

and i have no clue what the `?` is doing after PlayerIndex, it is an enum, and in the class every notice of it is with the `?` behind it.
my question: what does it do, what is it called and why would you use it.

I have googled this, but it didn't get me far since i dont know the name of this coding and google filters out the question mark in the search query

Comment: Try googling "C# nullable types".

Comment: With similar problems, try to come up with smarter google queries. For [c# question mark](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+question+mark) you get the answer right away.

Comment: Searching `[C#] "?"` in SO also works.

Comment: @DanielDaranas - that requires that you already know (most of) the answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I was trying to _help_ the OP by providing the search word he was missing ("nullable"), not criticizing his question. At the time of my writing, there were still no answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `?` makes `PlayerIndex` a `NULLABLE` type.

That way `controllingPlayer` can be `NULL` even if it is an `enum` or a basic type like `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The `?` is a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) type.  This means that `controllingPlayer` can contain `null` or a value.

To check whether there is a value associated with the variable, you can use `HasValue`.  To retrieve the actual value, use `Value`

```
if ( controllingPlayer.HasValue )
    // now do something with controllingPlayer.Value
```

Answer (score 3):

The question mark denotes that `PlayerIndex` is treated as a [`nullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) type.

Probably `PlayerIndex` is not a class or struct but an enum or alias for `int` or something like that. If it's an alias, you should find something like this in the code:

```
using PlayerIndex= System.Int32;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's short for [`Nullable<PlayerIndex>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) which means that you can pass a `PlayerIndex` value *or* `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` is indicating that `controllingPlayer` can be null. It could also be written as `Nullable<PlayerIndex> controllerPlayer`.

This is useful when working with valuetypes which can not be null, like reference types can be. If you have a regular `int`, you  cannot differentiate between a variable that is given the value 0 and a variable that is never written to. By wrapping it in a `Nullable<>`, you can now check if it has a value or not:

```
int notNullable;  //will be initialized to 0 by default.
int? nullable;    //will be initialized to null by default.

if (nullable.HasValue)        //Do something if the variable has been given a value
{

   return nullable.Value;     //get the actual int-value
}
```

See msdn documentation for nullable types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It means that the value type in question is a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Appending `?` to a type when defining something it is shorthand for wrapping in a [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) (see [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for further details). This means that value types, usually not able to express nullity, can be checked for a non-value instead of always resorting to their default (i.e., an `int`, rather than default to `0`, will default to `null`).

You may check whether or not the thing has a value, and access the value thusly:

```
var hasValue = nullableThing.HasValue;

var underlyingValue = nullableThing.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`PlayerIndex?` indicate that varible can be null value. The syntax T? is shorthand for System.Nullable, where T is a value type. please refer to [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).